# Excel Dynamics 365 connector and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-dynamics

Hello everyone I am trying to figure out how to establish a connection to Dynamics 365 using the VBA editor. Were doing a lot of updating to our fixed asset list at work and running into several issues on our company sandbox environment.

It would be very helpful if I could set up a macro to pull select information from multiple tables in a completely automated way.  This is currently done using the interface provided by the "Microsoft Dynamics Office Add-In", but I would like to code a more streamlined solution that does not rely on a human remembering the correct sequence of events.

Is there ANY documentation on this?  Even pointing me to the folder where excel installs add-ins from the store so I can pick through the files in the Object Browser would be a huge help.